# Empty user id for many value in child table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem in sqlalchemy. I have one to many  relationship:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    tags = relationship('Tag', back_populates='users')

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_name = Column(String(50))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    users = relationship('User', back_populates='tags')
```

When i save tags in this way

```
user = session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()
user.tags = [Tag(tag_name=tag_name)]
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

All tags saved but when o opened my db i see that only for last tag have value of user id and for other tags this filed empty.
[image]
But test must have user_id =1.
How can i fixed this problem?
For framework i use sanic and db is posgresql.
I want to save for user with id =1 many tags like: [user_id=1, tag='tad1'], [user_id=1, tag='tad2'] and [user_id=1, tag='tad3']. As a result i have may users but each users have own multiple tags.

Comment: The question as-is is not clear enough as the provided data only has one user and one tag, while the question is asking in the context of multiple users and multiple tags.  It would be useful to include additional code to insert the required data to demonstrate the actual problem that you wish to solve.

Comment: I edit my questions with describing my goal.

Comment: Yes, that is your goal, but you have not demonstrated how your code fails to achieve that goal because I cannot replicate your issue with the code you have provided.

Comment: All I see is, if I do `user.tags = [Tag(tag_name='tag0'), Tag(tag_name='tag1'), Tag(tag_name='tag2')]`, and then select for all tags, and `print([(tag.user_id, tag.tag_name) for tag in tags])`, I see `[(1, 'tag0'), (1, 'tag1'), (1, 'tag2')]` as output.

Comment: But what about db, why it's not visible in it?

Comment: You may have added that `test` tag on its own without a user previously, as your db schema does not exclude the possibility of having a null value for that column.

Comment: Are you using user.tags = [Tag(tag_name=tag_name)] to save tags one at a time? If so you may be overwriting all previous tags. Have you considered using user.tags.append(Tag(tag_name=tag_name)) to append additional tags vs overwriting previous tags?

Comment: Thank you very much @David Scott. It's help me!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell, because you are not showing the full context in which you are adding multiple tags, but if you are using something like this:

```
def add_tag(user_id,tag_name):
  user = session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()
  user.tags = [Tag(tag_name=tag_name)]
  session.add(user)
  session.commit()
```

ANd then executing it like this:

```
for tag in tags:
  add_tag(user_id=user.id,tag_name=tag.name)
```

Then because you use user.tags = [Tag(tag_name=tag_name)], you would be overwriting all previous tags rather than appending to them. This would explain why only the last tag appears to be connected to the user. To append new tags rather than overwriting you should use append() like so:

```
def add_tag(user_id,tag_name):
  user = session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()
  user.tags.append(Tag(tag_name=tag_name))
  session.add(user)
  session.commit()
```